# TCL socket client to Nodejs socket.io connection

Tags: node.js, linux, express, socket.io, tcl

I would like to make the connection between tcl socket to NodeJs server.

**TCL**

```
set serverChannel [socket 127.0.0.1 3500]

set startTime [clock seconds]

puts "client socket details: [fconfigure $serverChannel -sockname]"
puts "peer socket details: [fconfigure $serverChannel -peername]"
puts "socket error details: [fconfigure $serverChannel -error]"
puts [read $serverChannel]
puts "execution has been blocked for [expr [clock seconds] - $startTime] seconds"

close $serverChannel
```

**Output**

```
[root@localhost home]# tclsh socket.tcl
client socket details: 127.0.0.1 localhost 36127
peer socket details: 127.0.0.1 localhost 3500
socket error details:

execution has been blocked for 120 seconds
```

**Node JS**

```
const socket = new Server({
  cors: {
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:3500',
  },
  allowEIO3: true,
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  serveClient: true,
}).listen(listener);

socket.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {
  socket.send('Connected');
  console.log('Socket connected');
});
```

I don't know what is my mistakes unbale to make the connection.
But TCL return connection info.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with Node JS, but it seems to me like you are creating an HTTP server, capable of handling WebSocket connections. However, the socket on the Tcl side is just a plain TCP channel. Those do not match.

Upon connection from the Tcl side, the Node JS server expects an HTTP request header. When that hasn't arrived after 2 minutes, it gives up and closes the connection.

So you either need a WebSocket implementation on the Tcl side, or a raw-socket server on the Node JS side.

Comment: It seems that there's [some code in Tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/websocket/websocket.html) for this. I've not tried it out.

Comment: There's also [tclwebsocket](https://github.com/ecky-l/tclwebsocket) and [www::websocket](https://chiselapp.com/user/schelte/repository/www/wiki?name=www::websocket+manual+page). I haven't tried the former. I wrote the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue using **https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net**  instead of **https://socket.io/**